# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar Datepicker en español en Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy trabajando con Laravel, para el registro de usuarios necesito que ingresen su fecha de nacimiento, para ello estoy usando datepicker, pero el problema esta en que se encuentra en inglés el calendario. ¿Alguien sabe cómo pasarlo al español o algún otro calendario que pueda utilizar?

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que importar la configuración del idioma (en este caso español) después puedes cambiar el idioma por defecto.

Espero que te haya sido de utilidad.

Un saludo

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.fn.datepicker.defaults.language = 'es';
  $('.datepicker').datepicker();
});
```

```html
<!-- ESTILOS -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- JQUERY -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- DATEPICKER -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<!-- IDIOMA/REGION -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.es.min.js"></script>

Seleciona una fecha: <input class="datepicker"/>
```